# how to control when video finish in html

Tags: javascript, html, video

I made a video player following some tutorial and I want to control what happens when the video ends.
I want it to show 2 video thumbnails. Once you click on one of those, it would load asynchronously (without refreshing the page) and start playing by itself.

How can I proceed to do that ?

Here is my code:

**CSS**

```css
div#video_player_box{ width:550px; background:#000; margin:0px auto;}
div#video_controls_bar{ background: #333; padding:10px; color:#CCC;}
input#seekslider{ width:180px; }
input#volumeslider{ width: 80px;}
```

**JavaScript**

```js
var vid, playbtn, seekslider, curtimetext, durtimetext, mutebtn, volumeslider, fullscreenbtn;

function intializePlayer() {
    // Set object references
    vid = document.getElementById("my_video");
    playbtn = document.getElementById("playpausebtn");
    seekslider = document.getElementById("seekslider");
    curtimetext = document.getElementById("curtimetext");
    durtimetext = document.getElementById("durtimetext");
    mutebtn = document.getElementById("mutebtn");
    volumeslider = document.getElementById("volumeslider");
    fullscreenbtn = document.getElementById("fullscreenbtn");
    // Add event listeners
    playbtn.addEventListener("click", playPause, false);
    seekslider.addEventListener("change", vidSeek, false);
    vid.addEventListener("timeupdate", seektimeupdate, false);
    mutebtn.addEventListener("click", vidmute, false);
    volumeslider.addEventListener("change", setvolume, false);
    fullscreenbtn.addEventListener("click", toggleFullScreen, false);
}
window.onload = intializePlayer;

function playPause() {
    if (vid.paused) {
        vid.play();
        playbtn.innerHTML = "Pause";
    } else {
        vid.pause();
        playbtn.innerHTML = "Play";
    }
}

function vidSeek() {
    var seekto = vid.duration * (seekslider.value / 100);
    vid.currentTime = seekto;
}

function seektimeupdate() {
    var nt = vid.currentTime * (100 / vid.duration);
    seekslider.value = nt;
    var curmins = Math.floor(vid.currentTime / 60);
    var cursecs = Math.floor(vid.currentTime - curmins * 60);
    var durmins = Math.floor(vid.duration / 60);
    var dursecs = Math.floor(vid.duration - durmins * 60);
    if (cursecs < 10) {
        cursecs = "0" + cursecs;
    }
    if (dursecs < 10) {
        dursecs = "0" + dursecs;
    }
    if (curmins < 10) {
        curmins = "0" + curmins;
    }
    if (durmins < 10) {
        durmins = "0" + durmins;
    }
    curtimetext.innerHTML = curmins + ":" + cursecs;
    durtimetext.innerHTML = durmins + ":" + dursecs;
}

function vidmute() {
    if (vid.muted) {
        vid.muted = false;
        mutebtn.innerHTML = "Mute";
    } else {
        vid.muted = true;
        mutebtn.innerHTML = "Unmute";
    }
}

function setvolume() {
    vid.volume = volumeslider.value / 100;
}

function toggleFullScreen() {
    if (vid.requestFullScreen) {
        vid.requestFullScreen();
    } else if (vid.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
        vid.webkitRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (vid.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        vid.mozRequestFullScreen();
    }
}
```

Comment: please reopen the Question

Answer (score 1):

Please see the "ended" event for the video tag. I won't write the entire code for you, but I'll tell you the general process:

```
function showVideoSelector() {
    /*You must create a DOM for the menu, put it above the video or wherever, 
    and add some nice animations etc. :)
    Use the following functions to load and play 
    the selected video in the onclick event for your new menu.
    change someElement to something better... */
    ...
    someElement.onclick = function () {
        vid.src = "newVideo";
        vid.load();
        vid.play();
    }
}

vid.addEventListener("ended",showVideoSelector,false); // This is the important part
```

Comment: ok nice , but how can i say when the video finish , what is the event for that , and how to pass the name of the video selected , anyway am new to this so i really can not add code :D if u can help me i will be thankful to u sir

Comment: vid.addEventListener("ended",showVideoSelector,false); This is the "action" snippet. When the event "ended" is sent from the video tag (ie. the video ends) the "showVideoSelector" function is executed. The "showVideoSelector" should show a menu or some thumbnails or something from the next video. To play a new video you use the onclick function I wrote above (ie. 1. Change SouRCe, 2. Load video, 3. Play video). The menu code you have to write yourself, it is well beyond the scope of this question. Check out w3schools for some easy tutorials: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodes.asp